# Project not found when running DockerFile build command on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

This is the Dockerfile generated by VS2017 and it works well locally.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProj/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj", "MyProj.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.WebApi.dll"]
```

I have created a Build Pipeline under Azure DevOps to run Docker Build with these steps :

1. Get Sources Step from Azure Repos Git
2. Agent Job (Hosted Ubuntu 1604)
3. Command Line script `docker build -t WebApi ./MyProject.WebApi`

I have this error

```
2019-02-01T21:30:14.3797039Z COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder684976980/MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
2019-02-01T21:30:14.3910070Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2019-02-01T21:30:14.3994657Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

Attached screenshot 
[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Any suggestion?

Comment: well, this means you are building in the wrong directory, i assume

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41, I changed even the Working Directory pointing to MyProject.WebApi and now the error is about the Common project dependency.

Comment: i suggest you start a new question for that one, please

Comment: Done @4c74356b41

Comment: this is the new one with changes I have made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496114/project-dependency-not-found-when-running-dockerfile-build-command-on-azure-devo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the error was due to the script running in the wrong directory