# Project dependency not found when running DockerFile build command on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

This is the Dockerfile generated by VS2017.
I changed a little bit for using it on Azure DevOps

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
COPY ["./MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj", "MyProj.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.WebApi.dll"]
```

Solution structure

```
MyProject.sln
   -MyProject.Common
     ...
   -MyProject.WebApi
       ...
       Dockerfile
```

I have created a Build Pipeline under Azure DevOps to run Docker Build with these steps :

1. Get Sources Step from Azure Repos Git
2. Agent Job (Hosted Ubuntu 1604)
3. Command Line script `docker build -t WebApi .`

I have this error

```
2019-02-02T18:14:33.4984638Z  ---> 9af3faec3d9e
2019-02-02T18:14:33.4985440Z Step 7/17 : COPY ["./MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj", "MyProject.Common/"]
2019-02-02T18:14:33.4999594Z COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder671248463/MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj: no such file or directory
2019-02-02T18:14:33.5327830Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2019-02-02T18:14:33.5705235Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

Attached Screenshot with the working directory used
[image]

I don't understand if I have to change something inside Dockerfile or into Console Script step on DevOps

Comment: does it work locally?

Comment: I've tried so many times that I'm lost. Nope :( .... so my problem is that I don't understand how to run dockerfile starting from MyProject.WebApi root

Comment: well, according to the error, i think you are in the right directory, i just dont understand why this dockerfile implies myprojectcommon is a subdirectory of webapi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a hunch, but considering your `Dockerfile` is located under `MyProject.WebApi` and you want to copy files from `MyProject.Common` which is on the same level, then you might need to specify a different context root directory when running `docker build`:

```
docker build -t WebApi -f Dockerfile ../
```

When Docker builds an image it collects a context - a list of files which are accessible during build and can be copied into image.

When you run `docker build -t WebApi .` it runs inside `MyProject.WebApi` directory and all files in the directory `.` (unless you have `.dockerignore` file), which is `MyProject.WebApi` in this case, are included into context. But `MyProject.Common` is not part of the context and thus you can't copy anything from it.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Perhaps you don't need not specify `Working Directory` (shown in the screenshot), then the command would change into:

```
docker build -t WebApi -f MyProject.WebApi/Dockerfile .
```

In this case Docker will use `Dockerfile` located inside `MyProject.WebApi` and include all files belonging to the solution into the context.

You can also read about context in the **Extended description** for the `docker build` command in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Comment: Thank you Igor !  I made these changes COPY ["MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"] and COPY ["MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj", "MyProj.Common/"] . I run the command "docker build -t WebApi -f MyProject.WebApi/Dockerfile ." without setting the Working Directory and it works fine. Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!